# How to add a scroll bar in my JTextArea class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jtextarea

First, I know how to add a scrollbar in a JTextArea.

```
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollbar = new JScrollPane(textarea);
```

But in the following JTextArea class code below

```
public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea
{   
    public MyTextArea()
    {
        setEditable(true);
        setSize(500, 500);

        //JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(this);
        // ...
    }

}
```

How do I add a scroll bar? I tried using JScrollPane, but it didn't work. I tried making a new method, but it didn't work either.

This is my JFrame class.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{    
    MyFrame()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Frame Title");
        setSize(600, 600);  

        MyTextArea mytextarea = new MyTextArea();
        add(mytextarea);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

And my main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new MyFrame();
}
```

Comment: By default scrollbars will only appear when the size of the component exceeds the size of the scroll pane's viewable area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example that you've posted, you're not adding "a scrollbar in a JTextArea" you're adding the `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPanel`

Also, if you're not actually extending a class (adding new functionality to it) is better to create instance of that class and modify them instead, but, if you're set on doing that, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyTextArea extends JScrollPanel{   

    public JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

    public MyTextArea(){
        ta.setEditable(true);
        ta.setSize(500, 500);
        setViewPortView(ta);
    }
}
```

Comment: The setViewportView() make the whole frame a textarea.

Comment: @LordRixuel That is probably caused by the layout you've added this component to.

Answer (score 4):

Simply by wrapping the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`...

```
add(new JScrollPane(mytextarea));
```

will show the scrollbars when the component's content is larger then the scroll panes viewable area

[image: ScrollPane]

The question you really need to ask is, why are you extending `JTextArea`?  Have a look at [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=prefer%20composition%20over%20inheritance) more details